# Joomla - Remove product image zoom function

Tags: image, joomla, zooming

I am relatively new here but am looking forward to the support and knowledge i can gain here.

I have recently taken over a Joomla site that has a custom shopping cart which as far as i can tell is called dnaCatalog. I have tried to Google it but came up nothing but the actual dna workings of Joomla and other such things.

What i would like to achieve is to remove the image zoom from the product images in the shopping cart. I have searched the admin back-end through the plugins and modules but cant find any reference to any form of image zoom so I am guessing its hardcoded into the theme or catalog.

I currently have the site on a testing server here... http://geekdimm.com/ragland-current.

I have just updated it to the current version of Joomla 3.6.5

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zoom function is coded as a `JQuery` add on, you will find it at `templates/quasar/js/jquery.loupe.min.js`. The optimal way to solve this is to find the calls to the script above and remove them (be careful what you remove, you should know what you doing when editing the core files).

Alternatively look for the class called `loupe` which are associated to your images, this gives your images the zoom functionality.

The easiest (but dirtiest) way to solve this is to go to your templates css file 
`templates/quasar/css/template.css` and on line `7127` add the CSS `display:none!important;`

Comment: Many Thanks for this Sphinx, i will give it a go and let you know.